# How can I see list of albums I've shared on Google Plus, including the messages I composed

Tags: google-plus

I would like to look back and see messages and albums I've tried to send through Google plus.  I composed a long message and sent it and he album (I thought) to a friend and myself.  It never showed up in my email inbox, so I would like to retrieve the message and send it some other way.  Also wondering how to make sure these messages are REALLY sent in Google plus. I'm used to using Picasa Web Albums.

Answer (score 1):

If you share your Picasa url (https://picasaweb.google.com/yourname), the viewer will be redirected to Google Plus and see your albums in the G+ interface.

Another way is to get the url of one or your G+ albums (https://plus.google.com/photos/123verylongnumber890/albums/123anotherlongnumber890) and strip the last part/number.